# Disable IE Compatibility Mode for selected websites

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer

I know there's some well-supported methods for turning Compatibility Mode *on* for specific domains and addresses, but what about the reverse? In my case, I'd like to leave the settings open to the user, but by default have a short list of websites that *do not* render with Compatibility Mode enabled. It seems like there should be a simple way of doing this via GP that I'm just missing or not understanding. Anyone else approached an IE Compatibility Mode policy from this angle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compatibility View is already off by default. Internet Explorer decides to render a site with Compatibility View in one of three ways:

- An administrator uses Group Policy to set that site or the whole local intranet to render via Compatibility View
- The local users adds that site or the local intranet to the Compatibility View list
- Microsoft identified the site as needing Compatibility View during IE testing. This only happens for large sites that really need the feature.

If you're seeing sites render with Compatibility View that should not render this way, check your existing policies. You've likely erroneously enabled the local intranet to use CV.

If you need CV for a number of things on your local intranet, it's better to explicitly list those things in your Group Policy as opposed to turning on the CV for the whole intranet.

Comment: Thanks, Joel. Looks like I'll be dusting off RSoP and talking to our desktop imaging group.